# How can I group pushbullet notifications

Tags: google-apps-script, pushbullet

I am sending push notifications to my Android phone. I want these notifications grouped so my notification list does not get flooded.

According to the documentation messages from the same 'source' get grouped but on my phone the messages always show up ungrouped.

I call the push API from a Google Apps script and have tried setting source_device_iden, source_user_iden and notification_tag when I call the push API. None of these seem to make any difference.

How can I get the pushmessages to be grouped on my phone?

Google Apps script code

```
function pushNoteToPhone(title, body) {
   var digest = "Basic "+Utilities.base64Encode(PUSH_BULLET_TOKEN+":");
   var options = {
    "method" : "post", 
    "payload" : {
      "device_iden" : MYPHONE_ID,
      "type" : "note",
      "title" : title,
      "body" : body,
      "source_device_iden" : <device id>,
      "notification_tag": "tag1",
    }, 
    "headers" : {
      "Authorization": digest
    }
  };

  var push_bullet_url = "https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes";
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(push_bullet_url, options);
}
```

Comment: Do you have problematic code to share?

Comment: "According to the documentation messages from the same 'source' get grouped but on my phone"  <- Could you tell me where it says this in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (admittedly it should be easier) is to create an OAuth Client and then send using an access token for that oauth client.  That way the pushes will all appear to come from that client instead of you.  This is how IFTTT and Zapier work on Pushbullet.

Here's how to setup an oauth client: https://docs.pushbullet.com/#oauth

To get an access token you can use the "oauth test url" on the create client page, you will end up with an access token in the URL once you approve access.  Use that access token instead of your normal one and the pushes will appear to come from the client instead of you.

Comment: How would this make a difference? I then change the source client. Why would the message from this new client be grouped while this is not done for my current client?

Comment: As far as I can tell you are currently using no client at all, i.e. the "default pushbullet client".  Those are not grouped because it would for almost all users be the same as the "all pushes" group.  Using an oauth client causes pushes to be grouped.   I believe 'source_device_iden' is not used for grouping.

Comment: You could be right. It would be nice to know upfront but pushbullet employees do not seem to be very active on any channel. I will give it a try  to see if this is indeed the case.

Comment: I am one of the co-founders of Pushbullet.

Comment: It turned out it was easy to created the OAuth client. Your documentation is very clear on that part. And it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, sorry for the confusion with how to group messages though, that should be made more clear, it's sort of a side effect of the oauth stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how you are trying to update the notification but without the code, my guess is that you are trying to pass a new Notification ID to each notification being sent to the device. However, please take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Managing) and look under, "Updating Notifications". As explained in the documentation, by passing the same ID to each notification it will either group these notifications on the device or create a new one in case the old one has been dismissed.

Comment: I have added the code I use. You are refering to Android code. I do not have an Android app. That app is the pushbullet app. The question is about how the existing pushbullet app handles  the push message sent through the pushbullet API.