# Force pushbullet notifications not to group

Tags: notifications, pushbullet

When I send multiple pushes to a device, the notifications in the notification tray get grouped (at least that's what happens on my Android device). When I then remotely dismiss one of the pushes through the API because it's no longer relevant, the grouped notification doesn't update to reflect this, nor does it indeed disappear when all the pushes have been dismissed. It works if there's only a single notification in the device's tray, just not when multiple notifications are grouped. Is there any way to prevent the notifications from grouping? Or is there something that I'm doing wrong that prevents the grouped notification from updating? I'm using the V2 API and sending / dismissing link pushes as per the manual.

EDIT: I'm using an user access token because I've read in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986166/how-can-i-group-pushbullet-notifications?rq=1) that using an OAuth client would group the notifications which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve. Using an OAuth client actually behaved quite weird for me: only the first push would result in a notification, subsequent pushes would still be visible in the app but would neither create notifications of their own nor update the existing notification; only when I dismissed the first notification remotely would another notification pop out to take its place. But though making it work with an OAuth client would be even more preferable for my use I could just as easily continue to use an user access token if it helps.

EDIT 2: Experimenting further I found that if I push to a user using their own access token it works perfectly: I was able to push more than ten notifications to my own phone using my access token and they all appeared separately and I was able to dismiss them through the API. When I used a different user's access token the pushes started grouping as soon as the second one was received and there was no removing them anymore: neither updating the push with dismissed: true nor sending a DELETE request to the push would make it go away. So I guess I'll have to ask the users to provide their access tokens to the app (it's okay, it's just a couple of admins from the office next doors, so it's not random users sharing their access tokens with a stranger).

Comment: Are you using an oauth client + access token to create these pushes?

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: Pushes from other people are treated differently (and there's this weird distinction between oauth access tokens and internal access tokens), so I think that's probably what you ran into here.